# Open unity application via command line wih application's graphics off

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, terminal, unity3d

On [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) we can see there is a way to run a standalone player via command line without the graphics by typing -nographics

I'm using the following command on a mac terminal, but it is prompting the usual help message when we try to use 'open' with invalid flags.

```
open -nographics App.app/;
```

I would also like to perform the same command on a Linux server

Answer (score 1):

For the `open` command, to specify arguments that should be passed to the application, you need to use the `--args` flag. Otherwise, the arguments will instead be passed to the `open` command, rather than to the application.

```
open App.app/ --args -nographics
```

If you prefer to not have to do this (or if you want to see the console output in your Terminal window, which won't show with `open`) you can also directly call the executable inside the application:

```
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -nographics &
```

(The ampersand is optional; it sets the application to run in the background so you can continue using your shell, similar to `open`.)